# How to use charAt to find the location of a char in a string

Tags: java

So I didn't want to use the ascii table to do this. I want to make the user input an alphanumeric(eg A3) and then take the alphabet(A) and find it in the string ABC so itll give me a number between 1-9 instead of having the ascii values. This will make it easier for me to put in a 2d array later.

However when I use   System.out.println(abc.charAt(row));  itll say its out of bound bexception because its using the ascii value. How can I make it so that it doesn't

```
        public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
        String abc = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
        String ab = "abcdefghij";
        abc.equals(ab);
        System.out.println("Please enter the attack location:");

            while (!k.hasNext("[A-J a-j]+[0-9]")) {
                System.out.println("Wrong");
                k.next();
            }

            String location = k.next();
            char row = location.charAt(0);
            int num = (int) location.charAt(1);
            System.out.println(abc.charAt(row));
}
}
```

Comment: [`String#indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, the ascii character for `A` starts at 65, so if the user enters `A3`, then you're actually using `abc.charAt(65)`, which obviously is not what you want.

Instead, you need to find the index of the character in the array...

```
int index = abc.indexOf(row);
```

Have a look at [`String#indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) for more details

You may also want to use `Character.toUpperCase` to convert the `char` the user entered to uppercase, which will make it easier to search your `String`

ps- Also something like `row - 65` (or `row - 'A'` if that's to hard to remember) would give you the same result ;)